# Full page adverts?

Tags: support, advertising

Browsing SFF this morning on my phone and I <s>was hit in the face with</s> noticed a full page ad. The usual type that of full page ad that injects itself in the page and has that annoying hiding content scroll behaviour.

I'm using an iPhone and this was on Chrome on the full site with responsiveness disabled. That doesn't seem to be the issue though because normally adverts are where they should be not full screen. I haven't reproduced it on desktop because I sensibly use an adblocker there.

Are these types of adverts going to be allowed?

[image] [image] [image]

Comment: I'm afraid so. If they [do intend to display animated ads](/a/334144/350567), what can keep them back from fullscreen ads?

Comment: @iBug As much as I detest animated ads I can see why they'd be more willing to accept them than full screen ones.

Comment: This is honestly ridiculous. I'm glad that the Android app still works and is not tainted with ads.

Comment: @Script47 FWIW this is the first full page one I've seen but I certainly agree it is ridiculous.

Comment: It's the first and surely not the last. Maybe this specific ad is removed, but I'm 1000% sure others will follow and soon SE will announce "Sure, we now allow those ads", same way they did with animated ads. :/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thanks for reporting.  This will be removed immediately.

Comment: Thanks for this! I still find it poor that these sorts of ads are being allowed through in the first place though...

Comment: Removed maybe, but you don't even say it's not allowed in the first place. Well at least you don't lie. :)

Comment: What will happen to ads like this in future? will they also be allowed and removed after someone complains or just **allow** them? what's official policy on ads?

Comment: @Vishwa I get the feeling that the employees would like to be able to ban this sort of ad, but they can no longer count on those “at the helm” to back such a decision if it might reduce profits.  From a profits standpoint, now that you have great content, why NOT monetize the hell out of it?  It will take years and years for the quality of existing content to drop enough to really kill the business.  Sad but predictable.  A Renaissance of SE ideals would be great, but without the “goal setter” at the helm....

Comment: @Vishwa the fact we don't get a single reply to those questions is the answer we need.

Comment: @Shadow sadly, yes. so I'm tightening my ad blocker and I suggest everybody do the same until we get a proper, written, focused reply from the authorized party